# iReport v 5.2: How to calculate 2 variables with different reset types

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a report that should calculate with 2 variables that have different reset types.

The problem is that the last variable should be calculated on each "Cost type" group band. Bud variable Two is only known at the end of the report (on the summary band). For example:

```
Var_One / Var_Two = Var_Three <br/>
10 / 40 = 25% <br/>
20 / 40 = 50% <br/>
10 / 40 = 25% <br/>
```

The first one is the sum of the amount of a "cost type" Reset type = CostType_Group

```
<variable name="ondb_nkosten_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="kostensoort" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ondb_nkosten}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

The second one is the sum of the amount of a "costtype" Reset type = Report

```
<variable name="ondb_nkosten_3" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{ondb_nkosten}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

The third variable calculates the percentage between variable one and two.

```
<variable name="percentage_ksrgroep" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="kstgroep">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{ondb_nkosten_2} / $V{ondb_nkosten_3}) * 100]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an option I can use but i'm not completely happy with it. I hope there is a much simpler way of doing this, like the property "Evaluation Time" on a Field element.

I'm using a SubReport element in the title band to calculate Var_Three and parse it to the main report. Here I can use it in the formula.

I dare you guys to find an other way to do this. If you find one please let me know?